# What's the name of the song in mission 14 in Halo 5: Guardians?

Tags: halo-5-guardians, game-music-identification

In mission 14 of the campaign ("The Breaking") there is a beautiful piece of soundtrack combining the original Halo theme and the Halo 4 theme.

Occurrence:

> The song plays during charging through the Promethean lines until you reach the triple Warden Eternal.

Does anyone know if this song is part of the Original Soundtrack and if so, what the name of the song is?

**(MAJOR SPOILERS AHEAD)**
The song can be heard [here](https://youtu.be/cDXuLqj2o-g?t=11m10s) (video already starts at the correct spot). The song goes on for a few minutes.

Comment: Just listen to the original soundtrack? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b_qT9QNyfw

Comment: Maybe someone knows what song it is and has one minute to answer this question instead of me listening through more than 2 hours of soundtrack.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think you might be talking about The Trials

Comment: I'm gonna accept this as the answer because it's closest to what we here in the game at that point. In the game it is another medley which is not part of the OST on CD.

Answer (score -2):

blue team ost
is the name on the song :)

Comment: Uhm. Would you mind pointing to a source that verifies this?